# How to synchronize an arbitrary Windows folder with a Dropbox account?

Tags: windows, dropbox

How can I do this with Dropbox:

- I want to ensure that all my files stored under `C:\Users\Gerard\Images` and `C:\Users\Gerard\Documents` are stored automatically online.
- I don't want to copy them manually into the `C:\Users\Gerard\Dropbox` folder, since I'm very likely to forget things.
- I don't want to use twice the space on my hard drive duplicating all files from my images folder to my dropbox.

Should I:

- Stop using `C:\Users\Gerard\Images` to store things, and store everything under `C:\Users\Gerard\Dropbox\Images` instead? Or...
- Use a tool to synchronize my `C:\Users\Gerard\Images` and `C:\Users\Gerard\Documents` files with `C:\Users\Gerard\Dropbox`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [MKLINK](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753194%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) to create a directory junction between your DropBox folder and your Images and Documents folders, to fake out DropBox.

So for instance:

```
MKLINK /J C:\Users\Gerard\DropBox\Documents C:\Users\Gerard\Documents
MKLINK /J C:\Users\Gerard\DropBox\Images C:\Users\Gerard\Images
```

This creates a "fake" set of folders inside DropBox, without duplicating the data, and will upload all your photos and documents. In other words, there is an extra set of folders targeting the same location on the drive.

Whether you modify files in the "fake" or original locations, the folders will remain synchronised.

Comment: Note that this doesn't answer the Android part of the question (since it's out of scope for SuperUser.com). If anyone would like to edit this answer, please feel free.

Comment: Symlinks are great.

Comment: Exactly the answer I expected. So strange that this is not part of Dropbox userguide. Thanks for all Randolph.

Answer (score 0):

The dropbox folder on your PC acts as the local copy of whats stored on the dropbox server. To Sync both the storage you need to keep it in the assigned folder.

Comment: You don't **have** to do this. See my answer.